# Проверка орфографии в Android

Tags: java, android

Возможно ли  в Android при вводе пользователем некорректно написанного слова получить список всевозможных вариантов правильного написания этого слова. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: android studio - среда разработки, программа для того, чтобы писать и отлаживать код. К валидации ввода пользователя в приложении она не имеет никакого отношения (как, например, почтальон, к содержимому письма, которое он принес)

Comment: можете тогда подсказать библиотеки  или алгоритмы которые быстро находят слова близкие к тому что написал пользователь, дело в том что большинство  алгоритмов и методов нечеткого поиска не подходят из-за своей медлительности,  я попробовал  "расстояние Левенштейна" , но он работал по 3 секунды на каждый запрос это очень медленно.